# Properties of matrix stable (numerical) rank

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, spectral-theory, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

I happened to notice that there is concept "stable rank" that people used a lot in matrix computation theories, such as the work of [Rudelson & Vershynin (2005)](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503442v3). It is defined to be the ratio between squared Frobenius norm and the squared spectral norm of a matrix.
$$r(M) = ||M||_F^2/||M||_2^2$$

I was wondering if there is any literature or reference that discuss some basic properties of this stable rank. For example, do we know
$$r(M_1+M_2) \le r(M_1) + r(M_2)$$
which is expected to be true since the stable rank is expected to be more stable than rank?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the specific property does not hold. There can be many counterexamples.